# Stylus: prevent media tag from interpreting strings

Tags: stylus

We have an interesting dilemma.

I have a [PR](https://github.com/jescalan/rupture/pull/77) open for the [rupture project](https://github.com/jescalan/rupture/) to namespace the functions it exports in order to add a no-conflict mode.

First the actors

There are two functions (or mixins) that are named `landscape` and `portrait`. The PR namespaces them to `rupture-landscape` and `rupture-portrait`. The [@media](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/media.html) mixin is used throughout.

And now the scene.

With some of the functions created by rupture, a string is assembled to be used with the media tag. The end result should be a normal css media query.

The problem lies with the stylus @media mixin. It seems to automatically attempt to interpret the string and expand any keywords that might exist in the scope.

Since both landscape and portrait are within scope when not using no-conflict-mode, when ever the @media tag is used with a [composed string](https://github.com/jescalan/rupture/pull/77/files#diff-5f8ee28a7c08e245155174aaebb8532fR145) and `orientation: portrait` or `orientation: landscape` the result will prefix both the words `portrait` and `landscape` with `rupture`.

I've created a trivial example with a couple of attempts to fix the issue on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/BerkeleyTrue/pen/amPQER).

Here is the code as well:

Stylus

```
$landscape = 'notlandscape'
$string = "only screen and (orientation landscape)"
$unquote = unquote($string)
$s = s($string)

.foo
  // this is the main issue
  @media $string
    color: blue
  These two are attempts to fix the issue
  @media $unquote
    color: blue
  @media $s
    color: blue
```

and the compiled result in CSS

```
@media only screen and (orientation: 'notlandscape') {
  .foo {
    color: #00f;
  }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: 'notlandscape') {
  .foo {
    color: #00f;
  }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: 'notlandscape') {
  .foo {
    color: #00f;
  }
}
```

The actual desired output:

```
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  .foo {
    color: #00f;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent or circumvent this behavior?

Comment: Just to be clear here. Can you add the desired output?

Comment: I've added the desired output

Comment: And why not do the same that in your PR of rupture? `$string = "only screen and (orientation s('landscape')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [interpolation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html).  The referenced [@media](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/media.html) page also has a section about [Interpolations and variables](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/media.html#interpolations-and-variables) that will provide more info and examples.

```
landscape = 'notlandscape'
$string = "only screen and (orientation landscape)"

.foo
  @media ({$string})
    color: blue
```

Live @[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALzaNJ)

**Parenthesis are essential here.** So it's not exactly desired output but it's still valid CSS. How to avoid that (or if it's necessary) depends on use case. One idea:

```
landscape = 'notlandscape'
$string = "orientation: landscape"

.foo
  @media only screen and ({$string})
    color: blue
```

Live @[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Egzkbk)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was enough to get the test suite passing, although I do wish there was a cleaner way to do this.